# Псевдослучайные числа

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Генерация чисел метод середины квадратов(Нейтана) как он реализуется на с++?
но в результате выводит 0, а мне надо 125 чисел генерацией методом середины квадратов.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 125; j++)

for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
 {
    int  mid, sqr;
    sqr = x*x;
    mid = (sqr >> 8) & 0xffff;

    printf("x = 0,%x sqr = 0,%x  0,%x\n", x, sqr, mid);
}
_getch();
};
```

Comment: @dream, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: но в результате выводит 0, а мне надо 125 чисел генерацией методом середины квадратов.

for (int j = 0; j < 125; j++)
 for (int x = 1; x < 1; x++)
 {
  
  int  mid, sqr;
  sqr = x*x;
  mid = (sqr >> 8) & 0xffff;

  printf("x = 0,%x sqr = 0,%x  0,%x\n", x, sqr, mid);
 }
 _getch();

};

Comment: @dream, очевидно же, что возведением в квадрат, сдвигом вправо на 1/4 размера и сбросов 1/4 старших бит квадрата.

А сохранять результат между вызовами можно во внутренней `static` переменной.

Если хотите реентарабельную процедуру, то самое простое -- это возложить на вызывающую функцию ответственность за сохранность результат в локальной перменной (а для вычислений передавайте указатель на эту переменную).

Comment: @avp: А почему бы процедуре не принимать исходное значение, и не возвращать преобразованное? Вызывающий код сможет написать `seed = f(seed)` без всяких указателей. Pure functions — всегда хорошо.

Comment: @VladD, конечно, можно и так.

--

@dream, неужели Вы не замечаете, что 125 возводите в квадрат и т.д. *один и тот же* нолик?

--

Наверное вместо внутреннего цикла по `x` нужно (плюс к уже написанным вычислениям) просто еще и `x` менять (например, написать `x = res;`).

Только учтите, что последовательность может вырождаться (в пределе все числа станут одинаковыми). Это надо отслеживать и подправлять.

Comment: у меня всё равно 0 получаются

Comment: @dream, а Вы каждый раз новый код-то в обновление ответа 

(пишите там с новой строки **update**, потом пропускаете пару сторок и пишете код)

выкладывайте.

Откуда же нам знать, что Вы написали?

Answer (score 1):

насколько я знаю этот метод это - обрезать по 4 бита с каждой стороны, а вы делаете немного не то, но привести ваш код в нормальный вид можно вот:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 125; j++)
    {
        int   sqr;
        unsigned int  mid;//32 бита переменная
        sqr = j*j;
        mid = (sqr << 24);//оставляем 8 бит на значение, 
        mid >>= 16;//делаем более маленькие числа, 
/*но можно играться со значениями - тогда разница в сдвигах должна быть 
 *минимум - размер переменной в битах\4 т.е. при 32битах это 32\4=8 (24-16=8)
 *при unsigned short int это 16бит - 16\4=4 и при unsigned char это 8бит - 8\4=2.*/
        std::printf("%d, %d, %d\n" ,j, sqr, mid);
    }
    system("PAUSE>>VOID");
};
```

смотри сам сколько тебе нужна периодичность, но она будет в любом случае, в смысле смотря сколько ты оставишь бит на значение при обрезании старших, ты их можешь практически не обрезать.